# Admin login in magento PHP website not working with correct crendiantials

Tags: php, magento

I have magento website. Its admin panel is not working with correct credentials. when i comment this code

```
$cookieParams = array(
     'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
     'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
     'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
     'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
     'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
);
```

in `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php`
them my website shows blank page and after uncommenting this code my website again stops working and shows me a blank page.

Comment: have you tried removing all the files/folders from `var` folder from the main directory of magento installation??

Comment: @Ravi ,clear the cache and refresh the indexing in admin page

Comment: clear `var/cache` and `var/session` folders and try again.

Answer (score 4):

I d suggest you to never comment a code for any reason in app/code/core, especially if you don't know what it does.
In your case, you comment the basic storage of the session, so it will bring you a lot of bugs like that further, don't do it!

If you want to do some modifications on a core class, extend it but carefully!

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment this. Clear cache reindex and clean cache in your browser. Next try on incognito window.